# Write a test class for a lightning component which overrides a standard action

Tags: lightning, unit-test, action, component

I have written a Lightning Component that adds a google address lookup to a custom object.

I have replaced the standard new action with a new form.

How do I write a test class? I can't automate the click of a button to trigger the google lookup (which opens another modal window).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you try to get the code coverage for your Apex code, or do you want to do advanced testing? Is it not sufficient to appropriately call the Apex methods from your test class?

Comment: This should be comment rather than answer.

Comment: Correct.. I was overthinking it.